# utf-8 Unicode characters sporadically fail to output when using type to output unicode characters with virtual terminal sequences

Tags: batch-file, cmd, unicode, windows-10

Often when using type to output using unicode characters in conjunction with virtual terminal sequences, the unicode characters will fail to display correctly and be substituted with 'box' characters to represent them.

An example script [requires windows 10]:

```bat
:# Script for outputting a shaded multi color cube of size %1

 @echo off & Mode 1000,200 & Cls
 CHCP 65001 > nul

 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
 For /f %%a in ('Echo(prompt $E^|cmd')Do set "\E=%%a"

 If "%~1"=="" (
  Set /P "x=Enter cube size [1 - 30]: " & Call "%~f0" !x!
  Goto :Eof
 )

 Set /A "x=%~1,h=x*2,z=0"

(For /L %%y in (1 1 !h!)Do (
  Set /a "w=x-z"
  For /L %%a in (1 1 !w!)Do <nul set/p =%\E%7 
  For /L %%a in (1 1 !z!)Do If %%y LEQ %~1 (<nul set/p "=%\E%[38;2;0;120;%%a0m_|")Else <nul set/p "=%\E%[4m%\E%[38;2;120;0;%%a0m\\%\E%[0m"
  For /L %%a in (1 1 !x!)Do If %%y LEQ %~1 (<nul set/p "=%\E%[38;2;120;0;%%a0m▲▼")Else <nul set/p "=%\E%[38;2;0;120;%%a0m_\"
  If %%y LSS %~1 (Set /A z+=1)Else If not %%y LEQ %~1 Set /A z-=1
  Echo(%\E%[0m
 )
) >"%TEMP%\outfile.dat"
:# pipes typed file to findstr to correctly display UTF 8 characters

 TYPE "%TEMP%\outfile.dat"
 Del "%TEMP%\outfile.dat"
```

Example of failed output:

[image]

**So the question is, what can be done to prevent the unicode output from being incorrectly displayed when using type with [virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)?**

Comment: What happens if you explicitly redirect the `type` output to the console, i. e., `type "%TEMP%\outfile.dat" > con`?

Comment: Did a Battery of tests using  various utf-8 characters and console fonts, using `type "%TEMP%\outfile.dat" > con` to explicitely redirect to the con device. The syntax is also effective at ensuring the correct characters are output. I've added that method to the answer. Can you offer any insight as to why explicitely redirecting the output of `Type` to `Con` ensures the correct utf-8 characters are output?

Comment: As you know, `type` is intended to, well, type text file contents to the console; some particular characters or bytes become treated in a specific manner; I do not know by heart what happens to line-breaks, end-of-file characters or zero-bytes, but such characters may be altered, particularly when you specify a binary file; as soon as there is explicit redirection, no bytes/characters are altered in order to be able to also write binary data. Unicode text seems not to be well supported, so it could be interpreted as binary data…

Answer (score 0):

Ways to ensure correct output:

- **1.** Expicitly redirect the input from file to `Con` (thanks [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl)):

  - `TYPE "%TEMP%\outfile.dat"`**`> Con`**
- **2.** Pipe the typed file through `findstr`, using the `/V` switch and a 'false' string:

  - `TYPE "%TEMP%\outfile.dat"`**`| %__APPDIR__%\findstr.exe /V /C:"0x00"`**

```bat
:# Script for outputting a shaded multi color cube of size %1

 @echo off & Mode 1000,200 & Cls
 CHCP 65001 > nul

 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
 For /f %%a in ('Echo(prompt $E^|cmd')Do set "\E=%%a"

 If "%~1"=="" (
  Set /P "x=Enter cube size [1 - 30]: " & Call "%~f0" !x!
  Goto :Eof
 )

 Set /A "x=%~1,h=x*2,z=0"

(For /L %%y in (1 1 !h!)Do (
  Set /a "w=x-z"
  For /L %%a in (1 1 !w!)Do <nul set/p =%\E%7 
  For /L %%a in (1 1 !z!)Do If %%y LEQ %~1 (<nul set/p "=%\E%[38;2;0;120;%%a0m_|")Else <nul set/p "=%\E%[4m%\E%[38;2;120;0;%%a0m\\%\E%[0m"
  For /L %%a in (1 1 !x!)Do If %%y LEQ %~1 (<nul set/p "=%\E%[38;2;120;0;%%a0m▲▼")Else <nul set/p "=%\E%[38;2;0;120;%%a0m_\"
  If %%y LSS %~1 (Set /A z+=1)Else If not %%y LEQ %~1 Set /A z-=1
  Echo(%\E%[0m
 )
) >"%TEMP%\outfile.dat"
:# pipes typed file to findstr to correctly display UTF 8 characters

 TYPE "%TEMP%\outfile.dat" > Con
 Del "%TEMP%\outfile.dat"
```

Example of corrected output:

[image]

Comment: Redirecting _STDIN_ to the file `"%TEMP%\outfile.dat"` probably leads to an empty file, so you will see the data if the _STDOUT_ stream on the console rather than the output of `type` as you assume…